# regarding iphone app download count

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

how can i know the iphone application download  count of mine in itunesconnect..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of downloads of my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905059/number-of-downloads-of-my-app)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that, you have to login in iTunesConnect.apple.com site. Then go to "Sales and Trends" module. Here, you can find how many applications are downloaded.

Comment: itunesconnect.com is not itunes connect. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com

Comment: that is ok if i want to see daily or weekly downloads, but what if i want total downloads over the life of the app? or even a count of downloads per version of my app?

Comment: @JJMpls You need to use an app like [AppViz](https://appviz.com/) for that (and you need to maintain it regularly)

Comment: I guess if your app is free, the total # of "$0" transactions is how many downloads you got.

Answer (score 5):

See Sales and Trends section of iTunes Connect.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. but sales and trends option is not in my itunes connect.. what can i do..?

Comment: If you have purchased your iDP membership and your app is on the App Store, it must be there. Otherwise, there may be a problem with your account and then you should contact iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

The Sales and Trends option is available to you only if you are an Admin or have been granted "Finance" or "Sales" role.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/7_ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Go to itunesconnect.apple.com
 
Login 
 
Click "Sales and Trends" 
 
Here your top apps are listed.
 

 
To browse a specific one: 
 
Click "Add Filters"
 
Click "Content"
 
Fill in (part of) the name of your App
 
And voila.

This only shows when you have authority to view this data!

Answer (score 0):

For all details related to iOS App, login to your apple account on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/
Now you will see the menus given below in screenshot, click on **Sales and Trends**

[image]