# Number of downloads of my app

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there a way to find the number of downloads for my app in the iTunes App Store?

Comment: Is it your app, or someone else's app?

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897906/regarding-iphone-app-download-count .  Also questions about issues with the App Store are offtopic for Stack Overflow.  For business questions, I recommend asking on the iPhone Software Business mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesb

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can check the no. of downloads of your app using your Apple developer account.

Log into iTunes Connect and select the Sales and Trends tab.

A Sales, Finance, or Admin role in App Store Connect is required.

Comment: but der is no option like "Sales and Trends" in my itunes account..What i have to do..?

Comment: "Sales and Trends" can be found right after the login to iTunes Connect, just left of the "Manage Your Applications".

Comment: This only shows sales-by-week for the past 13 weeks.  Is there a way to find the all-time total downloads?

Comment: Yes how can we find out the total number of downloads and not week by week? Apple pssst!!!!

Comment: Sales and Trends can only be viewed if an appropriate role is enabled for a login. Not everyone can see that information."As an iTunes Connect user with an Admin, Finance, or Sales role, sign in to iTunes Connect."  For more information, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ViewingSalesandTrendInformation.html

Answer (score 20):

Just go to iTunes Connect, and hit "Sales and Trends".  It should give you the information you want. :)

Comment: but der is no option like "Sales and Trends" in my itunes account..What i have to do..?

Comment: @user: Ah, then you're looking in the wrong place.  It's in iTunes Connect, not in your normal iTunes account.  iTunes Connect is located here: http://itunesconnect.apple.com/

Comment: Have logged in the itunes connect itunesconnect.apple.com  account only but not able to find those options. Is there any separate membership required to see those options.

Comment: @user: That really is strange.  Did you submit the app using that account?

Comment: the app got approved yesterday only. Is there any time frame before which this option would appear. Or is there any hide options for the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any restriction like (in itunes connect)role as admin or legal ...?or technical...?

Comment: Trends don't usually appear until around 4AM PST (+- 2 hours) on the day after any actual customer downloads.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf: Hi in that i am able to check only weekly and daily sales detail. Is there any way to check total no of downloads since it is uploaded.